# jquery.exif not load exif data from displayed photo

Tags: exif

I cant get exif data from displayed image address

by click on photo You should see the exif data.

```
var someCallback = function(e) {
    $('#cameraModel').val(e.Model);
    $('#aperture').val(e.FNumber);
    $('#created').val(e.DateTime);
    $('#taken').val(e.DateTimeOriginal);
    $('#copyright').val(e.Copyright);
    $('#description').val(e.ImageDescription);
    $('#artist').val(e.Artist);
    $('#latitude').val(e.GPSLatitude[2]);
    $('#longitude').val(e.GPSLongitude[2]);
    //Uncomment the line below to examine the
    //EXIF object in console to read other values
    //console.log(e);
}

$('#fdd').on('click', function (e) {
    alert($(this).attr("src"));
    $(this).fileExif(someCallback);
});
```

please help... [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZS6bK/1/)

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't load jquery.exif.js? It turns out that you can't use that library directly in a fiddle because it uses document.write. If you paste the code from the plugin into your fiddle and delete the document.write snippet (which is only there for IE) then you get a bit further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the fiddle, you're trying to use the fileExif method from https://github.com/sanisoft/jQuery-fileExif. You have several problems here:

- You did not load the library in your fiddle (hence I had to guess which library you tried to use. Hint: read the console log, a message like `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fileExif'` means you're missing code or trying the call on the wrong object)
- That library cannot be loaded into a fiddle because it uses document.write. You can remove this code from the plugin to get it to work in a fiddle; it's only needed for IE:

```
document.write(
    "<script type='text/vbscript'>\r\n"
    + "Function IEBinary_getByteAt(strBinary, iOffset)\r\n"
    + " IEBinary_getByteAt = AscB(MidB(strBinary,iOffset+1,1))\r\n"
    + "End Function\r\n"
    + "Function IEBinary_getLength(strBinary)\r\n"
    + " IEBinary_getLength = LenB(strBinary)\r\n"
    + "End Function\r\n"
    + "</script>\r\n"
);
```

- You are using the wrong library. That one is for file uploads, not image elements. You should try using the original jquery exif plugin, here: http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/exifjquery/

Comment: Hello. Thank you 
I forgot to add the library .. but there is a problem with the library. And I need to use **fileExif** method.
Please see the new version of Fiddel : http://jsfiddle.net/ZS6bK/4/

Comment: Read the console errors. You *cannot* use images from that site in your fiddle, because they don't send CORS headers. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: An example of an image that does allow access: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/Calotes_mystaceus_manipur.JPG (look at response headers in developer tools) however, because jquery-exif tries to make a HEAD request, it also needs to make an OPTIONS request for CORS to work and wikimedia doesn't support this. All of these problems go away if you are hosting your own code instead of using a fiddle.